# New to Windows Programming, having trouble with a block of code

Tags: c++, windows

Can someone please tell me the problems with this piece of code?
I'm bulding a windows app, not a console. Am I using the functions
correctly. What types should I used? Okay I fixed semicolon err and
else err? Still not working properly.

```
#include <windows.h>
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE thisin,HINSTANCE previn,LPSTR lpstr,INT int_)
{
    LPTSTR buffer;
    DWORD size;
    SetConsoleTitle("Console Title");
    if(!GetConsoleTitle(buffer,size))
        cout << "error" << endl;
    else cout << *buffer << endl; 

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what makes you think there's a problem at all? The most obvious guess I can think of is that since you have a function named WinMain, it's being linked as a windows application, not a console application, so when you try to set the console title, it fails because there's no console.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin Well, it fails every time. But aren't these functions specifically used for the cosole. So what do you reccomend I do?

Comment: In comments you've said you don't want a console app. What *do* you think you'll accomplish by trying to set the console title with no console? Perhaps an even better question: what are you trying to do?

Comment: There is a lot more set-up code required to create a window, such as registering it with the OS.  See Petzold's book on Windows API, or use a framework such as wxWidgets or QT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It have 2 problems, first a ';' at end of if that is a C++ mistyping error and every body say it, but second is: for every API that get a buffer to return something, you should provide a valid buffer. Assume `GetConsoleTitle` implemented as:

```
BOOL GetConsoleTitle(LPTSTR p, DWORD dwSize)
{
    LPTSTR actualTitle = /* Get actual title from somewhere */;
    while (dwSize--)
    {
        *p++ = *actualTitle++;
        if (!*p++) return TRUE;
    }
    // Not enough buffer
    return FALSE;
}
```

Now look at your program, you pass an uninitialized `LPTSTR` to the function and as soon as API call `*p++ = *actualTitle++`, it will cause a segmentation fault or `Access violation`.
so in order to solve it, you must pass a valid buffer as first argument and since `LPTSTR` is a typedef of `TCHAR*` you should have:

```
const DWORD dwSize = 128;
TCHAR buffer[dwSize];
if (GetConsoleTitle(buffer, dwSize)) std::cout << "OK!" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help, but I thank you BigBoss espically. It works now :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is first. Your statement prints whether there is an error or not. Use an else there:

```
if(!GetConsoleTitle(buffer,size))
    cout << "error" << endl;
else
    cout << *buffer << endl;
```

and the `;` after your `if` was a typo, I corrected it above.

Answer (score 0):

You are using API's for Console App. Create a console app, copy this code to console project c or cpp source file and replace

> int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE thisin,HINSTANCE previn,LPSTR lpstr,INT int_)

with

> int _tmain(int argc, char *argv[])

also remove ';' (semicolon) from 'if' statement.

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work. And I'm not trying to make a console app.

Comment: The API's which you are using are for Console APP. For Win App there are alternates like for 'SetConsoleTitle' there is 'SetWindowText', 'GetConsoleTitle' there is "GetWindowText". What problems are you facing when following the procedure which I defined in above post? You haven't allocate memory for 'LPTSTR buffer'. Do 'TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH]' and size = MAX_PATH.